# Why is opening a file in rb mode not letting me strip some data from the read file contents?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code I wrote in Python that is supposed to take a compressed file with a ANSII header that is the file's extension written in caps. However when I strip try to strip that contents so that way I can pass it into zlib to decompress in order to import the file because the code to do it is in an import hook.

However it fails with this traceback all the time on the hook:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/make_zip.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pathlib import Path
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "path/to/py2pycx/_pycx_hook.py", line 96, in load_module
    filedata = f[len(b'PYCX'):].strip()
TypeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object is not subscriptable
```

And finally the code that I am using: that has this issue:

```
# other class stuff
def load_module(self, fullname):
    self.premodule = super().load_module(fullname)
    for ext in self.extensions:
        if ext == '.pycx':
            if self.premodule is None:
                try:
                    f = open(self.path, 'rb')
                    filedata = f[len(b'PYCX'):].strip()  # traceback happens here.
                    try:
                        decczfiledata = zlib.decompress(filedata)
                        decoded_data = base64.b64decode(decczfiledata)
                    except zlib.error as ex:
                        raise ImportError(
                            ('Could not import {0} because of exception:\n{1}.'
                             ).format(fullname, str(ex)))
                    self.module = decoded_data.decode("utf-8")
                    sys.modules[fullname] = self.module
                    f.close()
                    return self.module
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    raise ImportError('Could not import {0}.'.format(fullname))
```

Comment: You need to load the file data first by calling `f.read()`, you can't arbitrarily ask the reader to pull out a part of the file. Your `strip()` call will likely break because you're dealing with binary data. Also, for files you should also be using the `with` statement, like: `with open(self.path, 'rb') as f:`. It will close the file for you automatically, even if an exception is thrown

Comment: Your *immediate* problem isn't `strip`, it's that you are trying to slice a file-like object: `f[len(b'PYCX'):]`. That is not a defined operation.